# Create standalone product to channel advisor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, mechanize

```
url: "https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/Products?access_token=xxxxxxxxx"

body_params = {"Title":"string","Sku":"34123"}

'Content-Type'  => 'application/json'
```

All the things is completed but the request response is

```
400 => Net::HTTPBadRequest
```

please tell me that is i'm missing some thing?

Comment: Do you make a POST request to create a product?

Comment: yes. Anyway My problem is solved. The issue is when i repeat the  product's sku it return bad request response.